# Docker volume restore

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume, kitematic

I had a gitlab container in docker.
Today i have installed Kitematic and began to experiment. I choosed gitlab container -> Settings -> Network -> pressed 'CONNECT TO HOST NETWORK' and after that gitlab dead. After changing this setting back i have noticed that all settings are dropped now for this container. I think that container was recreated. Am i right?

I have found out some unused volumes. I'm hoping that some of these volumes contains my data which was lost after my experiments and container recreating.

How can i change volumes on existing container and how can i determine which of unused volumes was in use by previous instance of my gitlab image? And how to map them to corresponding docker folders like '/etc/gitlab', '/var/log/gitlab', '/var/opt/gitlab'? Maybe i can somehow browse them and it will help me to understand base on file structure everything?

All volumes are inside virtual machine and have no mapping to my host os drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gitlab docker file declared three volumes:

```
# Define data volumes
VOLUME ["/etc/gitlab", "/var/opt/gitlab", "/var/log/gitlab"]
```

Thus if you didn't name them when starting the first time, docker will automatically create volume with some random names. You can inspect each volume and see what files it actually contains:

```
docker volume ls
docker volume inspect <volume-name>
```

Locate the `Mountpoint` on the host analize which volume maps to which directory in the container. You can compare that with a fresh container by

```
docker exec -it <container-name> ls /var/opt/gitlab
```

Once you figure out which volume maps to which directory, recreate the container as such:

```
docker run <existing-volume1-name>:/etc/gitlab <existing-volume2-name>:/var/opt/gitlab ...
```

Comment: In addtition to this answere i have used this article to browse volumes folder on docker file system: http://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/ssh-into-docker-vm-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be recreated, yes. If you've run `run` instead of `start` this is the behaviour, but I'm not sure.

Volumes (one example):

`docker run -v your-vm-path:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab:latest`

Your data should be in your old volumes (local vm path). If not, you were not using those volumes.

If the data is in your local-vm paths (vols), see `docker cp --help` to put your data in your container or to get the data from your container.

For docker, your host is your virtual machine.